# How to display data in Primeng Datatable from Json file

Tags: json, angular, primeng

I have Data in Object form and I want to display it in Primeng Datatable but it display No record found.

data in json file

```
{
  "value1": "Value1",
  "value2": "value2",
  "value": "Value3"
}
```

this is how i get it in component file

```
this.http.get("app/components/my.json").subscribe((data) => {
        this.value = data.json();
    });
```

and here is how i am trying to display it

```
<p-dataTable [value]="values">
    <p-column field="value1" header="Value1"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gridMenuOptions` object needs to be an **array** type to bind to the `value` input property on the PrimeNG datagrid component.

It's not quite clear from the question but it doesn't look like your data is in that format? It would need to in this shape:

```
gridMenuOptions = [
  {quantity: 1, section: 'A', row: 1}, 
  {quantity: 2, section: 'B', row: 3}
];
```

Then you can bind it to a datatable definition e.g.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="gridMenuOptions">
    <p-column field="quantity" header="Quantity"></p-column>
    <p-column field="row" header="Row"></p-column>
    <p-column field="section" header="Section"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```